# coldfusion xml xslt premature end of file error

Tags: xml, coldfusion, menu

can anyone help me understand why this code block throws the xml premature end of file error?

```
    <cfxml variable="xslt">
        <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <!--- Start by matching the root node. --->
            <xsl:template match="/nodes">
                <nodes>
                    <!---
                        Inside our new root node, output all the top-
                        level NODE elements (ie. those with a parentID
                        value of zero).
                    --->
                    <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes" />
                </nodes>
            </xsl:template>
            <!--- This function outputs all child node elemenst of the node with the given ID. --->
            <xsl:template name="getChildNodes">
                <!--- Param our parent ID. --->
                <xsl:param name="parentID" select="0" />
                <!--- Select all the child node elements that have the given parentID. --->
                <xsl:for-each select="//node[@parent-id=$parentID]">
                    <!--- Sort this node list on ID. --->
                    <xsl:sort select="@id" />
                    <!--- Output the new node. --->
                    <node id="{@id}" parent-id="{@parent-id}" name="{@name}">
                        <!---
                            Now that are outputting a given node, let's
                            output all the child nodes that might be a
                            descendant of it.

                            NOTE: This is the recursive aspect of this
                            XSTL approach.
                        --->
                        <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes">
                            <xsl:with-param name="parentID" select="@id"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </node>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:transform>
    </cfxml>
```

the segment above is part of this full function:

```
<cffunction name="xmlNav" access="private" returntype="struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="qGetNav" type="query" required="true">
    <cfset var qNav = arguments.qGetNav>
    <cfset var rawNodeTree="">
    <cfset var xslt="">
    <cfxml variable="rawNodeTree">
        <cfoutput>
        <nodes>
            <cfloop query="qNav">
                <node id="#qNav.navid#" parent-id="#qNav.navparentID#" name="#qNav.TextDesc#"/>
            </cfloop>
        </nodes>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfxml>
    <cfxml variable="xslt">
        <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <!--- Start by matching the root node. --->
            <xsl:template match="/nodes">
                <nodes>
                    <!---
                        Inside our new root node, output all the top-
                        level NODE elements (ie. those with a parentID
                        value of zero).
                    --->
                    <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes" />
                </nodes>
            </xsl:template>
            <!--- This function outputs all child node elemenst of the node with the given ID. --->
            <xsl:template name="getChildNodes">
                <!--- Param our parent ID. --->
                <xsl:param name="parentID" select="0" />
                <!--- Select all the child node elements that have the given parentID. --->
                <xsl:for-each select="//node[@parent-id=$parentID]">
                    <!--- Sort this node list on ID. --->
                    <xsl:sort select="@id" />
                    <!--- Output the new node. --->
                    <node id="{@id}" parent-id="{@parent-id}" name="{@name}">
                        <!---
                            Now that are outputting a given node, let's
                            output all the child nodes that might be a
                            descendant of it.

                            NOTE: This is the recursive aspect of this
                            XSTL approach.
                        --->
                        <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes">
                            <xsl:with-param name="parentID" select="@id"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </node>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:transform>
    </cfxml>

    <cfset myXmlNav.xmlNav=rawNodeTree>
    <cfset myXmlNav.IsXml=IsXML(myXmlNav.xmlNav)>
    <cfreturn myXmlNav>
</cffunction>
```

I have confirmed I can run it on it's own outside the cfc

Comment: This is easy to debug. Remove lines from the contents of `<cfxml>` and see at what point it stops to work. The XSLT itself looks fine.

Comment: take a peak at my reply, I have tried removing everything, still no go

Comment: You have a single, empty `<cfxml>` in your CF page and this creates an error? Hard to believe.

Comment: yeah, it fails in the above example, it's like it does not the xsl formatting.  this is cf8 btw

Comment: Why not put the XSLT in a separate file and load that through `<cffile>` and `XmlParse()`?

Comment: hmm... that seems like overkill? I am working with this setup http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2045-Ask-Ben-Converting-A-Parent-Child-Data-Table-Into-A-Nested-XML-Document.htm

Comment: That's not overkill. And it keeps your CFML clean, too.

Comment: ok, I think I got more info, if I take this block out of the cfc it works on its own, however, in the cfc it blows up.  will add edits now

Comment: My question in comment #3 referred to an *empty* `<cfxml>`. Not even whitespace. Does that sill blow up?

Comment: yeah, that still blew up, with nothing in it, weird.

Comment: @Tomalak check out the lastest answer.  your suggestion fixed it.

Comment: No idea why your original code did not work, it was not wrong as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my solution completely and rolling with what I posted here: [coldfusion xml menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832256/coldfusion-xml-menu)  Thank you for your help @Tomalak.

Answer (score 1):

after reading various comments, I had to implement ben's solution as follows.  not sure if it was coldbox or something else, but here goes.

first here was the model method:

```
<cffunction name="xmlNav" access="private" returntype="struct" output="false">
    <cfargument name="qGetNav" type="query" required="true">
    <cfset var qNav = arguments.qGetNav>
    <cfset var rawNodeTree="">
    <cfset var xslt="">
    <cfset var xsltfile="#Instance.AppShared.AppServerInfo.ApplicationPath#\model\layout\MenuXsl">
    <!--- Reference: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2045-Ask-Ben-Converting-A-Parent-Child-Data-Table-Into-A-Nested-XML-Document.htm --->
    <cfxml variable="rawNodeTree">
        <cfoutput>
        <nodes>
            <cfloop query="qNav">
                <node id="#qNav.navid#" parent-id="#qNav.navparentID#" name="#qNav.TextDesc#"/>
            </cfloop>
        </nodes>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfxml>
    <cffile action="Read" file="#xsltfile#" variable="xslt"> 
    <cfset xslt=XmlParse(xslt)>

    <cfset myXmlNav.xslt=xslt>
    <cfset myXmlNav.xmlNav=rawNodeTree>
    <cfset myXmlNav.xmlNav=XmlParse(xmlTransform(myXmlNav.xmlNav,myXmlNav.xslt))>
    <cfreturn myXmlNav>
</cffunction>
```

and second here is the xslt file:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/nodes">
        <nodes>
            <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes" />
        </nodes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="getChildNodes">
        <xsl:param name="parentID" select="0" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//node[@parent-id=$parentID]">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" />
            <node id="{@id}" parent-id="{@parent-id}" name="{@name}">
                <xsl:call-template name="getChildNodes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parentID" select="@id"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I had to remove all of the comments too

Comment: The comments are perfectly valid ColdFusion comments. They won't break anything.

Comment: I figured as much, just thought I would try it, but no dice